# how to know when user click on a bottom on a web page that opened inside the app

Tags: flutter, tracking

how to track user activity by exmple i want to open youtube.com/some channel/ when user click on subscribe botton i wanna to know how it is posiable in flutter.

if it is posiable by flutter_matomo or any other lib let me konw please help me i realy need it.

how to track user activity by exmple i want to open youtube.com/some channel/ when user click on subscribe botton i wanna to know how it is posiable in flutter.

if it is posiable by flutter_matomo or any other lib let me konw please help me i realy need it.

Answer (score 0):

After some search i found flutter webview as the sloution

https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter